# Trying to understand the standard deviation's formula

Tags: standard-deviation

I have just started learning standard deviation and I'm trying to understand the formula.

$$ s = \sqrt{ \frac{\sum(x-\bar x)^2}{n-1} } $$

**Can anyone explain to me the square (and square root) part?** If they are using the square & square root to prevent having negative value, why not just use | | for absolute value?

And I have another question. Why is the $-1$ sometimes omitted?

$$ \sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\sum(x-\bar x)^2}n} $$

**Should I -1 or just omit it?** I googled the standard deviation formula and some show -1 while some don't.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just to prevent negative values: standard deviation has many nice 
mathematical properties that your alternative proposal would not.  In particular, the absolute value function is not differentiable at $0$.

The reason for the $-1$ is to make $s^2$ an unbiased estimator of the variance.
See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_standard_deviation#Sample_standard_deviation

Whether you should use it or not may depend on what you're using it for.